# ClosedXML Change existing Footer / Header

Tags: c#, closedxml

How can I change an existing header / footer (`PageSetup`, `OddPages`) with ClosedXML? With `AllPages` the missing header / footer (`FirstPage`, `EvenPages`) was created, but not changed for `OddPages`.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
worksheet.PageSetup.Header.Center.AddText("New Text");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't change an existing header / footer text. But you can read the existing text, clear the header / footer and then set a new / changed text.

Use something like this (here for odd pages):

```
var oldHeaderText = worksheet.PageSetup.Header.Center.GetText(XLHFOccurrence.OddPages);
var newHeaderText = "New Text (" + oldHeaderText + ")";
worksheet.PageSetup.Header.Center.Clear(XLHFOccurrence.OddPages);
worksheet.PageSetup.Header.Center.AddText(newHeaderText, XLHFOccurrence.OddPages);
```

Comment: Please provide more information. How does your code look like? What should it do and what does it?

Comment: I have an existing Excel workbook with a header `(Odd Pages)` and will write a version number in the middle. So nothing bad. For testing, I have made myself a simple Excel sheet with header. Then put the statements shown and save the Excel workbook with a different name. After opening has not changed. 
`XLWorkbook  worksheet.PageSetup.Header.Center.Clear(XLHFOccurrence.OddPages);
            worksheet.PageSetup.Header.Center.AddText("New Text", XLHFOccurrence.OddPages);
            workbook.SaveAs("d:\\test.xlsx");`

Answer (score 0):

It might or might not work depending if you're starting from scratch (works) or trying to modify an existing workbook (doesn't work)...
https://closedxml.codeplex.com/workitem/9441